# module pattern for interdependant objects

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am looking for a clean design pattern in Node.js to allow me to put two classes in separate modules when each references the other.

Eg:  I have `Node` and `NodeCollection` objects.  Obviously `NodeCollection` must know what a `Node` is,  but `Nodes` themselves hold a `NodeCollection` object for their children.

Currently I am configuring the Node constructor when I require it.

**nodeCollection.js**

```
const Node=require('./node')(NodeCollection)

 function NodeCollection(....){
   // do stuff with Node objects
 }

 module.exports = NodeCollection'
```

**node.js**

```
function Node(NodeCollection){
  function _Node(...){
     this.children = new NodeCollection();
     //do stuff
  }

  return _Node;
}

module.exports = Node;
```

Is there a better way to design this?

Addendum:  There seems to be some misunderstanding:  I am not asking for a better design of NodeCollection or Node objects.  These were offered as a toy example.  Often, in such examples, the two classes cannot be agnostic about each other.  I am looking for a way to set up Node.js Modules when faced with such an arrangement.  I could solve the problem by putting both classes in the same module but they are large and complex enough that they warrant their own files.
Thankyou

Comment: Consider typescript. :)

Comment: why are you passing a the collection constructor to your model constructor? just `require` the model and collection definitions in each of your files.

Comment: Because, as I explained, the Node objects need to use a NodeCollection to hold their children

Comment: Perhaps if you gave examples of what you're actually trying to do rather than toy examples, it'd help us help you.  I'll say that most problems I've seen in JavaScript are best solved after forgetting most of what you use in classical inheritance based languages.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think in your case you need to distinguish between `Node` and `Nodes`. Something basic like this will give you a tree structure.

```
class Node {
  constructor(data) {
    this.data = _.omit(data, 'children');
    this.children = (data.children || []).map(child => new Node(child));
  }
}

const tree = new Node({
  name: 'bob', 
  children: [
    { name: 'bill' },
    { name: 'jim' },
    { name: 'luke' }
  ]
});

// yields...

{
  data: {name: 'bob'},
  children: [
    {
      data: {name: 'bill'}
    }
    ...etc
  ]
}
```

Comment: I do need a NodeCollection object, a simple array as in your example, will not suffice in my design.  NodeCollection has specialized properties and methods not available on the standard Array

Comment: put them in the `Node` class then. every node and child node is an instance of the same constructor so you can give a `node` methods as well.

Comment: These are both LARGE classes.  Combining them would make things very unwieldy, which is exactly the purpose of splitting them into separate modules